# NEST API : using Rest Services : Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache

Tags: curl, dns, nest-api

We are following the link   "https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/how-to-auth"   for accessing the thermostat details in the Google nest.

we were able to perform step 2 to get the credentials for authorisation(PIN)  and step 3 Exchange your authorization code for an access token.
the log for step 3 is given below where we get the acces token from the google server

```
    ====================Requesting Nest server for Access Token==============
    root@buildsys:~# curl --data    'client_id=46694fbc-a66c-4e30-91bd-ce8f4a58258d&code=JKL2369W&client_secret=ULVfZ3xYZvxOWHgtLLe5gUqAe&grant_type=authorization_code'  https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token
 /*Curl output for access token*/   

    {"access_token":"c.G8YcMzNFKk3STuQSx8qVSk9etBmUD5T6S2Wbq9eiDdxtyiMH34Ci6QBR8l3s1Xx1bC8u8B0lrsz55zvuYzR2vBEIdfRZCCPMc9qOAK6RDuo2EZ9uFsY9EVCVd5K24MMrFkkjyCV71SZiVuNv","expires_in":315360000}
root@buildsys:~#
    ===========================================================================
```

we are using curl version 7.40 as shown below

```
 ====================Curl Version ======================================
    root@buildsys:~# curl --version
    curl 7.40.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.36.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28
    Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
    Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
    ======================================================================
```

Further we are using REST services and we are using the rest example for making calls to Nest API but we are not successful in this as after certificate verification, when redirected to firebase URL it is giving 
    "Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache". The log for the same is given below.

```
====================Calls to Nest API ==================================
root@buildsys:~# curl -v -L https://developer-api.nest.com/devices.json?auth="c.G8YcMzNFKk3STuQSx8qVSk9etBmUD5T6S2Wbq9eiDdxtyiMH34Ci6QBR8l3s1Xx1bC8u8B0lrsz55zvuYzR2vBEIdfRZCCPMc9qOAK6RDuo2EZ9uFsY9EVCVd5K24MMrFkkjyCV71SZiVuNv"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.243.68.228...
* Connected to developer-api.nest.com (54.243.68.228) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*        subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=developer-api.nest.com
*        start date: 2014-04-10 21:26:03 GMT
*        expire date: 2015-04-10 21:26:03 GMT
*        subjectAltName: developer-api.nest.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /devices.json?auth=c.G8YcMzNFKk3STuQSx8qVSk9etBmUD5T6S2Wbq9eiDdxtyiMH34Ci6QBR8l3s1Xx1bC8u8B0lrsz55zvuYzR2vBEIdfRZCCPMc9qOAK6RDuo2EZ9uFsY9EVCVd5K24MMrFkkjyCV71SZiVuNv HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: developer-api.nest.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache, max-age=0
< Location: https://firebase-apiserver02-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553/devices.json?auth=c.G8YcMzNFKk3STuQSx8qVSk9etBmUD5T6S2Wbq9eiDdxtyiMH34Ci6QBR8l3s1Xx1bC8u8B0lrsz55zvuYzR2vBEIdfRZCCPMc9qOAK6RDuo2EZ9uFsY9EVCVd5K24MMrFkkjyCV71SZiVuNv
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Closing connection 0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://firebase-apiserver02-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553/devices.json?auth=c.G8YcMzNFKk3STuQSx8qVSk9etBmUD5T6S2Wbq9eiDdxtyiMH34Ci6QBR8l3s1Xx1bC8u8B0lrsz55zvuYzR2vBEIdfRZCCPMc9qOAK6RDuo2EZ9uFsY9EVCVd5K24MMrFkkjyCV71SZiVuNv'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.87.176.38...
* connect to 54.87.176.38 port 9553 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to firebase-apiserver02-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com port 9553: Connection refused
* Closing connection 1
curl: (7) Failed to connect to firebase-apiserver02-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com port 9553: Connection refused
root@buildsys:~#
============================================================
```

But we are able to change the temperature value of thermostat and set to away mode and all operations can be performed in the web browser but in the rest services it is not working.

Kindly help me to solve the problem.

Regards
Shashi.